# How to pass parameters to parallel process using pipeline plugin in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have below code in Jenkinsfile.Step 1: has list of values. Step 2: passing that list to function. Step 3: trying to pass the value dynamically to java jar.But the values are not assigned properly. Because It is assigning in step (4) and then triggering that process concurrently (5).

```
def numToEcho = [1,10,20,27] ---(1)

def stepsForParallel = [:]

for (int i = 0; i < numToEcho.size(); i++) {
def s = numToEcho.get(i)
    def stepName = "echoing ${s}"

    stepsForParallel[stepName] = transformIntoStep(s) --(4)
}
parallel stepsForParallel  --(5)

def transformIntoStep(inputNum) { ---(2)
    return {
        node {
            echo inputNum
def tb = sh script:' java -jar titanRead.jar $inputNum', returnStdout:true  --(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass list values to jar. Like below in parallel process.

```
Sh ‘java -jar TitanRead.jar 1’  
Sh ‘java -jar TitanRead.jar 10’  
Sh ‘java -jar TitanRead.jar 20’  
Sh ‘java -jar TitanRead.jar 27’
```

Inside jar I am reading like arg[0]..and it is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException..but If I run the jar separately in terminal it is working..How can I do that..Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline in your question doesn't seem to match your description, as `java jar TitanRead.jar` won't work; you'd need to use `-jar`.

In any case, your `sh` `script` parameter should be using a double-quoted string, otherwise `$inputNum` won't be evaluated, i.e.:

```
sh script: "java -jar TitanRead.jar ${inputNum}"
```

Comment: Thanks ..It was my fault..I missed out "-jar"( I have edited it)..I am using double quotes as you said..It is working now..java jar is taking arg[0] and printing the output. but for some value it is showing following error " script.sh : unterminated quoted error" can u plz help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Got it..It is because, some of my input has appended with special character..Thank you so much ..:)